# calling a java method in velocity template

Tags: templates, velocity

I have a class `CurrencyUtil` in which I have written a method `convertCurrency(String symbol, long value)` I want to call this method from velocity template. I am putting object of this class `map.put("formatter", currencyUtil);` and in template I am using the tag as `$formatter.convertCurrency($currency, $total)` but when the template is rendered it is not printing the result.

here my question is that, should the parameter names in the java method and in template be same? or is there any other problem?

Comment: eatSleepCode's comment on apatian's answer resolved the problem for me, too. So, it might help others, too: mine problem was parameter type mismatch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Parameter names in java method and template can be different. You may try to locate your problem using the following example.

**Example.java**

```java
package com.example.currency;

import org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
import org.apache.velocity.Template;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import java.io.*;

public class Example
{
    public Example(String templateFile)
    {
        try
        {

            Velocity.init("velocity.properties");

            VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
            CurrencyUtil cu = new CurrencyUtil();
            cu.setCurrencyRate("EUR", 1.25);
            context.put("formatter", cu); 

            Template template =  null;

            try
            {
                template = Velocity.getTemplate(templateFile);
            }
            catch( ResourceNotFoundException rnfe )
            {
                System.out.println("Example : error : cannot find template " + templateFile );
            }
            catch( ParseErrorException pee )
            {
                System.out.println("Example : Syntax error in template " + templateFile + ":" + pee );
            }


            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

            if ( template != null)
                template.merge(context, writer);


            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Example t = new Example("example.vm");
    }
}
```

**CurrencyUtil.java**

```java
package com.example.currency;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CurrencyUtil {
    private static Map<String, Double> rates = new HashMap<String, Double>();

    public double getCurrencyRate(String symbol){
        return rates.get(symbol);
    }
    public void setCurrencyRate(String symbol, double currencyRate){
        rates.put(symbol, currencyRate);
    }

    public double convertCurrency(String symbol, long value){
        return value * getCurrencyRate(symbol);
    }
}
```

**example.vm**

```java
#set( $total = 10000000000)
#set( $currency = "EUR")
$formatter.convertCurrency($currency, $total)
```

Comment: I did same thing, mine problem was parameter type mismatch. Thanks for the answer after so long time.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity receives all parameters as `String`s. In your function you receive a `String` and apply a cast.